# Does anybody know what these bright curved lines are?

Tags: lens, sony, zeiss

Shot with the Zeiss 35 2.8 on my A7iii. Any input is much appreciated!

[image: Uncropped Photos]
Also, here is some other shots I did, with some other settings too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any filters on your lens?

Comment: Not sure about the lines...but iso2500 in midday?

Comment: Are the lines in all three images aligned (if you rotate all images into the same orientation)? Does it occur in other images

Comment: Is there a lens hood on your lens?

Comment: @Hueco yeah, I know it's high, but it seems like the higher iso-settings are revealing the curves more.

Comment: @xiota It was no hood on that day. I'll take some more pictures today to see if that might be the issue. If it turns out that is really the issue, would you know anything about what would cause those lines?

Comment: @mattdm I'm gonna meassure it and come back to you with an answer quickly!

Comment: @mattdm I just put the 3 photos on top of each other, and the lines are placed exactly at the same spot. So we can probably exclude any random glimmering then.

Comment: That's actually really interesting...so the lines are worse at ISO2500 than, say, ISO100?

Comment: @Hueco I'll go out and shoot a couple of new photos now with some different settings, and we'll see.

Comment: @Hueco if you take a look at the post again, I have added 6 photos with diffetrent settings. The settings is shown in the footer. Thanks for your dedication!

Comment: Are the clouds in your planet, similar as ours? :o)

Comment: @Rafael We don't have clouds on our planet actually. Fortunately, we do have Zeiss-lenses! :D

Comment: Weird request: can you take a long dark frame image (such as, ISO 2500, f/2.8, 5 minute shutter, lens cap on) and post it?

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the same lens you do, but I have a different 35/2.8 lens that appears to exhibit similar behavior when light is shining into the lens. If you can get the arcs to come and go depending on the position of a lamp shining into the lens, then the problem is likely **flare**.

Here is a sample photo taken with a lamp shining toward the camera from the right.  Moving the lamp shows different portions of the arc on the left.

[image: without hood]

Using a lens hood may reduce the problem.  Here is a photo taken with lens hood, at the approximately the same position as the above photo.

[image: with hood]

Similar appearances are known to have been caused by [filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46064/75526).

[image: filter reflection]

Some combinations of lenses, teleconverters, and sensors are known to produce flare-like artifacts, such as hot spots and blue dots.  This is a possible scenario if using the same lens with different equipment produces different artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess rather than a definitive answer.  However there it points to some experiments you could do which would indicate whether it is correct or not.

First of all all of your examples show the lines on a clear blue sky.  Secondly I *think* that, if you extended the curves to circles, the centres of those circles would perhaps appear to be at the opposite point to where the Sun is in the sky.  Finally the patterns *don't* appear to be aperture-dependent, and in particular they don't appear only when the lens is wide-open or nearly wide-open.

So my guess is that what you are seeing is some kind of artifact due to polarization of the sky.  Light from the sky comes from [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) of sunlight, and it is [significantly polarized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_sky_model).  The degree of polarization depends on the Sun, but it is greatest at 90 degrees to it, dropping to zero both where the Sun is and opposite it.  This means that if you measure the polarisation of the sky you will see arcs of circles both surrounding the Sun and surrounding the point opposite it.

So I hypothesize that something in the camera's optical system – either the lens or the sensor – is sensitive to polarization, and what you are seeing is some artifact due to that.

As I said above: this is a hypothesis not a definitive answer (but it was way too long for a comment).  There are two obvious experiments you could do to see if this is true:

- check whether the centres of the arcs really are opposite the position of the Sun (this means they will be below the horizon of course);
- do some experiments with a polarizing filter to see what that does to the artifacts.

Finally it's also possible that the lens is seeing something else in the sky: these patterns kind of look like rainbows (which also centre on the point opposite the Sun): the reason I'm suggesting polarization is that this is something you would *not* see with your eyes.  If they are some brightness/colour change, then you should be able to see it with your eyes (although it may be faint), and other lenses should see it.  Such faint rainbow-like artifacts might occur because of aerosols in the atmosphere I think ([aerosols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosol) in this context means a suspension of small particles in the atmosphere: fog & clouds are aerosols, but there are many other kinds, including ones as a result of human activity).

One variant of the above suggestion is that the optical system of the camera might be sensitive somewhat into the infrared or ultraviolet, and what you are seeing is indeed a rainbow, but one which has only IR or UV components.  I would have to do the maths about this but I suspect that UV-only rainbows might be a possible result of aerosols with very small particle sizes.  I'm not sure IR-only ones make sense in the same way.  You could test for this by getting a UV filter and seeing if the artifacts go away.

Note that *all* these suggestions fail if the arcs are not centred on the point opposite the Sun!